# URLs not preserved with Angular routing and Spring Security due to "#"

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, angular-routing

I am facing a problem where our application using Angular JS must have Spring Security added to it. Spring security now works. The problem is that after the request to the server is made for authentication everything after the "#" in the URL is now lost. I know that this happens because browsers drop everything after the "#" in the URL before sending to server.

My question is, how can I then route the user to the appropriate page when log in is successful, if that information has been lost? What is the best way to accomplish this?

Clearly that information must be handled on the front-end if you want to retain the URL after "#" following the log in. I am not, however, sure on whether this is something spring-security can maintain for me or how to maintain it myself.

For example, lets assume this is my angular routing setup:

```
        .when('/addProducts', {
            templateUrl : 'resources/template/addProduct.html',
            controller : 'addProductController'
        })
        .when('/viewProducts', {
            templateUrl : 'resources/template/viewProducts.html',
            controller : 'viewProductController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl : 'resources/template/home.html',
            controller : 'homeController'});
```

For example, lets assume a user is not logged in and requests the following URL: **`http://localhost:8080/myApp/#/viewProducts`**
After the user is logged in the server comes back with **`http://localhost:8080/myApp/`**  (having lost everything after "#" when it was submitted to the server)

Angular routing now has no choice but to hit the "otherwise" statement and end up on home.html. This is not the view products page that they wanted.

If someone could shed some light on how to make this work, that would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Additional information: Here is my spring security file:

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <headers>
        <cache-control/>
    </headers>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />


    <form-login />

    <logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true"/> 

    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
    </session-management>

</http>

<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>spring_security</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!--  Add Users below -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service properties="classpath:users.properties"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Why not use real, clean URLs thanks to html5Mode? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: Hmm that could work if it gets rid of hashes for me. I am attempting to implement this right now but the documentation isn't making it clear on exactly what I need. Do i need anything besides <base href="/myApp"> and $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)? It doesn't look like it, yet i cannot get it working.

Comment: That's all you need at client-side. A server-side, you need to be serve the index.html page for all the URLs of your application, in case the user refreshes or bookmarks a page.